# I'm trying to find some hotel public phone numbers in Google using Python and Google Maps API, but my Python code can't find any phone number

Tags: python, google-maps, google-search

This is my Python code:

```
import requests 
import json

def search_place(api_key, place):
    base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?"
    inputtype = "textquery"
    fields = "formatted_address,name,formatted_phone_number"
    locationbias = "ipbias"

    request_url = f"{base_url}input={place}&inputtype={inputtype}&fields={fields}&locationbias={locationbias}&key={api_key}"

    res = requests.get(request_url)
    data = json.loads(res.text)

    return data

api_key = "<my api key>"  

hotel_list = [
    "White castle",
    "Mihilaka holiday homes",
    
]

with open("hotel_numbers.txt", "w") as file:
    for hotel in hotel_list:
        data = search_place(api_key, hotel)
        if 'candidates' in data and data['candidates']:
            hotel_data = data['candidates'][0]
            name = hotel_data.get('name', '')
            phone = hotel_data.get('formatted_phone_number', "Can't find")
            file.write(f"{name}: {phone}\n")
        else:
            file.write(f"{hotel}: Can't find\n")
```

Can someone solve my problem or give a solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

### If the field you want is not returned by Find Place, you can use Find Place to get a `place_id`, then use that `place_id` to make a Place Details request

I tried running your code in my own environment, tweaked it a little, and I can see that your function returns an `INVALID_REQUEST` error saying that the fields you entered are invalid. As per the documentation,

> **Place Search** requests and **Place Details** requests do not return the
> same fields. **Place Search** requests return a subset of the fields that
> are returned by **Place Details** requests. If the field you want is not
> returned by **Place Search**, you can use **Place Search** to get a `place_id`,
> then use that **Place ID** to make a **Place Details** request.

What that means is that instead of using **Find Place** to get all the details you want, you cann just use it first to get the `place_id` and use **Place Details** instead to get all the details you want. See [Place Details documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details) for more information. But it says there that,

> Once you have a `place_id` from a Place Search, you can request more
> details about a particular establishment or point of interest by
> initiating a Place Details request. A Place Details request returns
> more comprehensive information about the indicated place such as its
> complete address, **phone number**, user rating and reviews.

You have to take note though to use the [**fields** functionality](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details#:%7E:text=If%20you%20do%20not%20specify%20at%20least%20one%20field%20with%20a%20request%2C%20or%20if%20you%20omit%20the%20fields%20parameter%20from%20a%20request%2C%20ALL%20possible%20fields%20will%20be%20returned%2C%20and%20you%20will%20be%20billed%20accordingly.%20This%20applies%20only%20to%20Place%20Details%20requests.) to cut some cost.

With that said, your code should look like this:

```
import requests 
import json

def search_place(api_key, place):

    # Use place search first to get the place_id to be used for Place Details request later.
    place_search_base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?"
    inputtype = "textquery"

    # Set the fields for place_id only to cut cost.
    fields = "place_id"
    locationbias = "ipbias"

    request_url = f"{place_search_base_url}input={place}&inputtype={inputtype}&fields={fields}&locationbias={locationbias}&key={api_key}"

    res = requests.get(request_url)
    data = json.loads(res.text)

    return data

api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"  

hotel_list = [
    "White castle",
    "Mihilaka holiday homes",
]


for hotel in hotel_list:
  data = search_place(api_key, hotel)
  if 'candidates' in data and data['candidates']:

      # Here we try to fetch the place_id
      hotel_place_id = data['candidates'][0]["place_id"]

      # create another base url for Place Detail request
      place_details_base_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?"

      # This should be the place to put the fields you want to cut cost.
      place_details_fields = "name,formatted_address,formatted_phone_number"

      place_details_url = f"{place_details_base_url}place_id={hotel_place_id}&fields={place_details_fields}&key={api_key}"
      place_details_res = requests.get(place_details_url)

      # Convert the response to json
      place_details_data = json.loads(place_details_res.text)

      # Then fetch the name and the phone from the Place Details result
      name = place_details_data["result"].get('name', '')
      phone = place_details_data["result"].get('formatted_phone_number', 'can\'t find')

      # This should print the name and the formatted phone number if it exists.
      print(f"{name}: {phone}\n")
  else:
      print(f"{hotel}: Can't find\n")
```

With this code, I got these results:

```
White castle: Can't find

Mihilaka Holiday Homes: 070 337 2732
```

I hope this helps!